# Combined centered legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I am using `patchwork` to create a combined plot with a common legend that is centered on the top.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

x1 <- ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, col=Species))+
       geom_point()

x2 <- ggplot(iris,aes(Petal.Width, Petal.Length, col=Species))+
       stat_ellipse(show.legend=F)

wrap_plots(x1, x2, guides="collect") +
  theme(legend.position="top",
        legend.direction="horizontal")
```

This is what I get.

[image]

This is what I was expecting.

```
ggpubr::ggarrange(x1, x2, common.legend=T)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `+` instead of `&`. See [here](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/assembly.html#modifying-everything) for the differences between operators:

1. With `+` the theme layer is only applied to the last plot, i.e. `x2` in your case which has no legend
2. If you want to apply to all plots you have to make use of `&`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

x1 <- ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, col=Species))+
  geom_point()

x2 <- ggplot(iris,aes(Petal.Width, Petal.Length, col=Species))+
  stat_ellipse(show.legend=F)

wrap_plots(x1, x2, guides="collect") &
  theme(legend.position="top",
        legend.direction="horizontal")
```

[image]